# How to retrieve user specific data along with elasticsearch results?

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch for searching ecommerce product store.Now there is a scenario where  a user adds a product to wish list by clicking "heart" icon in mobile app.

Now when a user searches something and user has added a product to wish list we want user wishlist along with search result so that we can show user that product is in wishlist and for that we need to store wishlist and retrieve along with search result.

Should user data be stored in seperate index or as a child ?

How to retrieve user data along with search result ?

If I store it in child then there would be too many updates to the product document.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same question. Can you put your solution here?